# Brother 5350DN: check how many print with toner

Tags: printing, printer, brother-printer

i have a brother 5350DN link with usb cable to my pc,
is there the possibility to check how many print have done the toner inside the print ? 
i try to print the printer information but i can see only the total page printed in all life of the printer but not the partial printed with the current toner. i try also to reset the toner sequence with this procedure:

With Printer off open the toner door
Hold the Go button as you turn the printer on.
All lights will turn on. Keep holding Go until status light goes off.
Press the Go button 2x.
The Paper, Drum & Toner light will come on
Press Go 6x
Status light will turn red
Close the front.

but there is no changing in the total printed page of the summary printer report.
How can i check the printed page for the current toner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any printer that will tell you the number of pages per cartridge, only the number of pages since first power on. The only thing you can do is to note the page count when a cartridge is empty, and note it again when the next one is empty. That will tell you the number of pages the last cartridge did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Good page counter, free for the future, also you can see, how many page you can print with the toner, in the manufactured website or the toner box.

now install the page counter and read something the amount of printer,

**How to install a page counter on my printer**

http://www.en.rellenadodecartuchos.com/2013/01/how-to-install-page-counter-for-my.html

if need more help, please ask me...